# Logic app -send email with attachment-"Unable to parse template language expression 'base64('triggerBody()?['contentBytes']')': "

Tags: json, http-post, azure-logic-apps, email-attachments, azure-http-trigger

Working on sending email on http trigger with attachments in logic app. Providing json input as below

```
{
    "properties": {
        "bcc": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "body": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "cc": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subject": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "to": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "attachments":{
            "name":{
                "type":"string"
            },
            "ContentBytes":{
                "type":"string"
            }
        },
        "type":"object"
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

passing attachment in base64 string format.
But while configuring attachments for content variable getting an error

> Unable to parse template language expression
> 'base64('triggerBody()?['contentBytes']')': expected token
> 'RightParenthesis' and actual 'Identifier'.".'

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to click on `Add dynamic content` and use the following expression:

```
base64(triggerBody()?['attachments']?['ContentBytes'])
```

[image]